# Develop app for Android using OpenCV code

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-ndk

I'm new to opencv for android. I know C/C++ but don't know how to program in Java. 
I've developed a code in C/C++ using OpenCV. Now I want to port this code for Android OS. Please tell me about some tutorial or give me some instructions following which I can easily port that code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The developer.android.com site has a lot of examples, including how to call C++ from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Android can run c++ as a part of your code. Check android NDK

Comment: I know Android can run this code.... but I want to know How can I call C/C++  methods from java source using NDK??

I've to use images in that code.